# Not able to install Teams on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt

When I try to install Teams on my Ubuntu 16 laptop by command

```
sudo apt-get install teams
```

I get the below error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 teams : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.12) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Looks like you have to upgrade Ubuntu 16 which is EOL since April 2021, to a newer version.

Comment: In theory you could install the libgtk-3.0 from a newer Ubuntu on your Ubuntu 16 but it is a horrible idea. Most likely that package will also need new packages, which also need new packages and so on. You will end up with something that looks like a upgraded distro in broken state. Follow the advice of A.B and upgrade your whole distro cleanly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install `teams` from [flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.microsoft.Teams):

```
 sudo apt install flatpak
 flatpak install flathub com.microsoft.Teams
```

Or [via snap](https://snapcraft.io/install/teams/ubuntu):

```
sudo snap install teams
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 Flatpak can be installed through:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install flatpak
```

Or from "Flatpak" team ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable
```

Comment: sudo snap install teams did the trick. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there the OS requirement for "flatpak" tool? I am not able to install in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @CloudCho See my edit.

Comment: both of these currently fail on Ubuntu 22.04  ...  `sudo snap install teams
error: snap "teams" not found`  ...  and for flatpak error is `error: Failed to install com.microsoft.Teams: While downloading https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/pool/main/t/teams/teams_1.5.00.23861_amd64.deb: Server returned status 404: Not Found`     ... Microsoft if you are listening please fix these